# Datadog tracer not displaying traces for python GCP Firestore AsyncClient

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, trace, datadog

I am using datadog tracer (https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_collection/dd_libraries/python) to investigate performance issues in a fastapi python API.

Each call produces one trace.

For a reason I can't get, my calls don't produce traces when I hit this route:

```
from google.cloud import firestore

@router.post("/test")
async def test() -> dict[str, Any]:
    client = firestore.AsyncClient(project=CONFIG.gcp_project)    
    document = await client.collection("my_collection").document("my_id").get()
    return document.to_dict()
```

My http client is able to print the returned dict, indicating that the request ends up in status 200.

When I comment the line below I have a trace:

```
    document = await client.collection("my_collection").document("my_id").get()
```

Did I forget some specific configuration ? (https://ddtrace.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

`firestore.AsyncClient` might not be supported. But what puzzles me is that I should get at least one trace (with the root span as the only span), shouldn't I ?